# Counting specific words within a string, that arise in a specific order

Tags: r, string, stringr, detect

1) I'd like to count the number of times my students could state 5 specific words (each student has their own string).

2) I'd like to create another column that states whether or not students' responses were in the correct order (correct order= "green - yellow - orange - red - black").

3) I'd also like to create a column which counts the number of ORDER mistakes students made.

All the data is in lower case and each term is separated by " - ". Sometimes people repeated words (e.g. they had two answers "red" and "very red"), the "red" should get a point but the "very red" should not. I also do not want to award points for words like "reddest" which contain the correct string "red". The amount of answers each student gave out of five was variable, ranging from 0 terms to 6.

```
#     Student responses
Id    DF$Colors
1     green - yellow - orange - red - black
2     yellow - green - orange - reddest - black
3     red - violet - pink - black
4     purple - green - orange - red - black
5     blue - pink - yellow - scarlet
6     green - yellow - orange - red - very red - black
7     orange - green - yellow - red - black
8     orange - green - yellow - black - red
```

The output I'm aiming for is:

```
Id  DF$Colors                                         DF$CountCorr DF$CorrOrder  DF$OrderMistakes 

1   green - yellow - orange - red - black             5            TRUE          0
2   yellow - green - orange - reddest - black         4            FALSE         1
3   red - violet - pink - black                       2            TRUE          1
4   purple - green - orange - red - black             4            TRUE          0
5   blue - pink - yellow - brown                      1            NA            NA
6   green - yellow - orange - red - very red - black  4*           TRUE          0
7   orange - green - yellow - red - black             5            FALSE         2
8   orange - green - yellow - black - red             5            FALSE         3
```

*answers with 6 terms should be deducted a point. I've been able to get the count column by doing this:

```
all_colors <- c("green", "yellow", "orange", "red", "black")
library(tidyverse)

DF <- DF %>%
  left_join(DF %>%
             separate_rows(Colors, sep = " - ") %>%
             group_by(Id) %>%
             summarise(CountCorr= max(sum(all_colors %in% unique(Colors))- 
                               sum(duplicated(Colors)), 0)))
```

However, I'm struggling to calculate the columns which detect whether the order is correct, and how many order mistakes were made.

Please note, I asked a similar question 3 months ago, but did not get the solution I was after

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(DF)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(DF, 20))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Barradas, the output of dput(head(DF, 8)) was...

Comment: c("green - yellow - orange - red - black", "yellow - green - orange - reddest - black", 
  "red - violet - pink - black", "purple - green - orange - red - black", 
  "blue - pink - yellow - scarlet", "green - yellow - orange - red - very red - black", 
  "orange - green - yellow - red - black", "orange - green - yellow - black - red")

Comment: I had head(DF, 20) then changed to 8 because the posted data has only 8 rows. Then I changed it back to 20 because I noticed the `group_by` instruction in the pipe.

Comment: Yes my actual DF has 3317 rows